# Need help finding installed_app setting in Django

Tags: python, django

I am having trouble finding where the installed_app setting is in the django folder. i can't seem to find anything related to this "setting". Can anyone help?

Comment: i have found it, thanks for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

All settings of the project or application are set in the settings.py file. Describe what kind of settings you want to change.

Answer (score 1):

**INSTALLED_APPS** is a list, and located in mysite/settings.py (at the top of the file).